# SCM and maven - using SCM through Maven or Eclipse?

Tags: svn, maven, subclipse, pom.xml

If I am using subversion through eclipse (subclipse, subclipse maven handler), then I don't need to add maven:scm information to settings.xml, right? Are there any other reasons why I may need to add the SCM information to my project or maven settings file? I plan on using continuous integration in the future.

It just seems kind of pointless to add SCM information anywhere within the maven project object model, if eclipse is managing all of that for me, but then again I may naive. I heard somewhere down the grapevine that CI tools look for SVN info inside of poms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the SCM information in your maven build to be able to do a release via Maven. Furthermore it is a good idea to put the information for information purposes if you creating the web-site via maven site. The information about using scm information via CI is not correct. You can decide not to put the scm information into your pom but it's best practice to do in particular in relationship with release process where it's necessary.

Comment: Oh I see, because Maven downloads a copy of the source from SCM before it packages it (for the release)? It does not create the build using files from the working copy?

Comment: In case of using mvn release:prepare and release:perform yes. The checkout of the tagged version will be done during release:perform step which is logical from the software configuration management point of view, cause this makes sure that exactly the state from the version control is used to create the release artifacts instead and undefined state from your working copy.

Comment: so in that situation, I should put the SVN tag in the PROJECT pom, and then the credentials securely password protected in my own settings.xml file right?